# VBA GetAsyncKeyState in PowerPoint captures same key multiple times

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to use GetAsyncKeyState to capture an arbitrary two stroke key alpha sequence in PowerPoint, e.g., "AA", "AB", "DZ".  However, I am finding that the first key stroke is being captured as both the first and the second.

For simplicity, the below code tries to capture only the sequence "AA".  I would expect the code to complete after "A" is pressed twice.  However, it completes as soon as "A" is pressed once.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer

Private Const VK_A = &H41 'A key


Sub CaptureAA()

    ' Capture first 'A' keystroke
    Do While True
        If GetAsyncKeyState(VK_A) Then
            Debug.Print "First A captured"
            Exit Do
        End If
        DoEvents
    Loop

    ' Capture second 'A' keystroke
    Do While True
        If GetAsyncKeyState(VK_A) Then
            Debug.Print "Second A captured"
            Exit Do
        End If
        DoEvents
    Loop

End Sub
```

I'm guessing I need to somehow discard the key press after the first GetAsyncKeyState, but I'm not sure if that is right or how to do it.

Comment: Assuming `DaoEvents` is a retypo...

Comment: Yes, must have gotten there when I was testing, the "A" key.  Thanks for catching.

Comment: Smells like an X-Y problem... what are you *actually* trying to do?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, in terms of what I'm actually trying to do.  I'm trying to label each shape on a slide with a keyboard shortcut, e.g., "AA" and then invoke an action on the labeled shape when that keyboard shortcut is invoked.

Comment: Have you considered letting PowerPoint handle the keyboard stuff and configuring your macros with actual shortcut keys (which would be Ctrl+Key)?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, I've looked at it; although, I can't claim to have exhausted that option.  The challange I've found and what I'm trying to work around is that there is no good way to quickly select a given shape (without using the mouse).  I know I can tab to it, but I was trying to create something fater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're casting the return value to a `Boolean` when you test it, so you're going to pick up the "recently pressed" bit in addition to the key state.  From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) for the API:

> Although the least significant bit of the return value indicates whether the key has been pressed since the last query, due to the pre-emptive multitasking nature of Windows, another application can call GetAsyncKeyState and receive the "recently pressed" bit instead of your application. The behavior of the least significant bit of the return value is retained strictly for compatibility with 16-bit Windows applications (which are non-preemptive) and should not be relied upon.

That said, this is likely not ever going to work reliably.  If you want to do this reliably, you'll probably need to subclass the host window. Every time you call `DoEvents` in your loop you risk dropping keystrokes.

You also need to account for case where the user types <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>{Any}</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.  The only thing you can really do with an external loop trying to spy on the "real" message pump is determine if they were down twice in quick succession. In order to rule out any other key being pressing in the interim, you need to monitor *all* the keyboard events.

Comment: Thanks; not exactly the answer I was hoping for but very helpful none the less.